# AlpineJs dont update on binded property

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I want to update property a binded (x-model) property on keydown.

But it does not work at all.

Do I something wrong here?

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hsrkge1/)

```
<div x-data="app()" class="w-64">
   <input x-ref="textInput" x-model="textInput" x-on:keyup="limitInput($el)" type="text">
</div>


function app() { 
  return {
    textInput: '',
    limitInput($el) {
       this.textinput =  ''
    },
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are limiting the length of the `input` to 0 using `maxlength="0"` this way nothing can be added inside the `input`.
Also, what are you trying to do with the `limitInput` function? because calling it on `keydown` will call it before the input is updated with the key pressed, if you want to call it after, use `keyup`.

Comment: Hey Paul-Louis! This maxlength="0" is something I tested. I forgot to delete it. 
So - now I cleaned it up. I don't use `maxlength` anymore I use `keyup`.
I want to limit the input with the limitInput function. So anytime the user types in - he is not able to do so - because `textinput` is resetted to ''. This does not work.

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from inputing data, why don't you use the `disabled` HTML attribute instead?, like so: `<input x-ref="textInput" x-model="textInput" disabled type="text">`, you can remove it later if you need to enable the input again

Comment: Because this is not the real functionality I want to implement. 
I build a select2 like blade component with alpineJs. 
And I actually want to disable the input when I have reached a specific limit. 
So this is just a snipped with a functionality broken down on what is not working.

Comment: Disable the input when you've reached a specific limit like, a characters limit? or from other parts in your code?